# Get specific process name from dotnet core console application on ubuntu

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

i'm writing a simple console application and try to get it's process by it's process name. 
The console app ist written with c# .net core 2.0 and it's running under ubuntu.

In the process list under ubuntu it is only appearing as 'dotnet' which is not specific enough. I would like to get name according to ist dll/exe name.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you trying to get the current running process id?

Comment: Yes I do. I want to determine between different dotnet core processes which is currently not possible.

Comment: So you want the current process always in the console app? Or you have multiple processes and you want to get a certain process from any of them?

Comment: Scenario: I have different dotnet core console programs. I want to find a certain of it. Under windows it could be dentitfied with it's name which could be helloworld.exe. Under linux with dotnet core everything is called dotnet. So I can't find my program among others.

Comment: Getting my own process inside a program is not the matter.

Comment: Maybe try building a [self-contained native linux](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/Documentation/self-contained-linux-apps.md) distribution of the program instead of running it through dotnet